# Extjs menu directing page

Tags: extjs, menu

What's the best way to direct menu pages?
Is it necessary to add it to handler or we can directly use xtype and how?

```
`Ext.define('MyApp.view.menu.Menus', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
requires: [
    'Ext.menu.Menu'        
],

items: [{
    text: 'Menu item 1',
    handler: 'item1'
}, {
    text: 'Menu item 2',
    handler: 'item2'
}
```

}`

Can we use xtype?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that this is what you're asking. You have two options for controlling/directing the menu: either using a specific handler, as was mentioned above, or using a common listener.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).